# Executing URLs in Python similar to curl in Linux - JenkinsAPI

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, curl

I am trying to trigger some builds using a shell script by doing the following :

```
export url='http://test.com';
export job_name='MY_JOB_NAME';

jso="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\":\"BRANCH\",\"value\":\"master\"}, {\"name\":\"GITURL\",\"value\":\"https://github.test.com/test/test.git\"}]}";

curl $url/job/$job_name/build --data-urlencode json="$jso";
```

This works fine, but when I try to convert it to a python equivalent, it doesn't seem to trigger the URL:

```
import requests
import json

url='http://test.com/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build'

params={'name':'release_1.5', 'GITURL':'https://github.test.com/test/test.git'}
payload = json.dumps(params)
resp = requests.get(url=url, data=payload)
```

This executes without any error, but it does not trigger a build on my CI machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things you're doing wrong here. The first thing which I hope is apparent is that the JSON data you're sending is completely different.

Beyond that, the primary issue you're having here is that your curl is doing a POST with urlencoded data in the BODY, and your python request is doing a GET with urlencoded data as separate parameters in the url. Change your .get to a .post, and the params= to data= and you should be a whole lot closer to your intended goal.

```
resp = requests.post(url=url, data={'json':payload})
```

Also note, I embedded your payload into a key as json, as that's what is happening in your curl. I'm not fully aware of your implementation details, but I hope that this helped put you on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

Add the content-type to the header of the request, i.e.:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
...
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```